# How do I get the correct output for my clock created with java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, stack-overflow

My Teacher has given me this assignment. She gave us a ClockTester.java main program and we have to create a public class that declares the objects and methods to use in the Clock Tester. Below is the Tester, and below that is my clock.java code. I am having trouble getting it to format to 00:00:00 like she wants. I have also put her instructions guide.

If someone could please, please help me out here. 
Also I am getting a stack overflow error when I try to run the program.

[Instructions from my teacher](http://file:///Z:/Desktop/CSCI%201301%20Fall%2016/CSCI1301Project7.pdf)

```js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//Program:  ClockTester
//Author: D. Spence
//Date:  April 4, 2014
//Purpose: Tests the features of the Clock class
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClockTester
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  //Declare five objects in the Clock class
  Clock c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;

  //Initialize Clock objects using constructors
  c1 = new Clock();
  c2 = new Clock(15);
  c3 = new Clock(8,30);
  c4 = new Clock(12,5,45);

  //Show all four objects
  System.out.println("c1 is " + c1);
  System.out.println("c2 is " + c2);
  System.out.println("c3 is " + c3);
  System.out.println("c4 is " + c4);
  System.out.println();

  //Determine if clock times are past noon
  System.out.println(c1 + " is " + (c1.isPM() ? "after noon" : "at or before noon"));
  System.out.println(c2 + " is " + (c2.isPM() ? "after noon" : "at or before noon"));
  System.out.println(c3 + " is " + (c3.isPM() ? "after noon" : "at or before noon"));
  System.out.println(c4 + " is " + (c4.isPM() ? "after noon" : "at or before noon"));
  System.out.println();

  //Manually set a value
  c1.setTime(14,15,30);
  System.out.println("Changed c1 to " + c3);

  //Test for equality
  System.out.print (c1 + " is ");
  System.out.print ( (c1.equals(c3)) ? "equal" : "NOT equal");
  System.out.println (" to " + c3);
  System.out.println();

  c5 = new Clock(15,0,0);
  System.out.print (c5 + " is ");
  System.out.print ( (c5.equals(c2)) ? "equal" : "NOT equal");
  System.out.print (" to " + c2);
  System.out.println();


  //Demonstrate math operations
  System.out.println ("\n Some Clock Operations:");
  System.out.print (c1 + " + 10 hours is ");
  c1.addHours(10);
  System.out.println (c1);

  System.out.print (c3 + " + 45 minutes is ");
  c3.addMinutes(45);
  System.out.println (c3);

  System.out.print (c4 + " + 90 seconds is ");
  c4.addSeconds(90);
  System.out.println (c4);

  System.out.print (c4 + " + 12:59:55 is ");
  c4.addTime(12,59,55);
  System.out.println (c4);

  //TestBonus();

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("This concludes the test of the Clock class.");
  System.out.println();

 }

/*
 public static void TestBonus()
 {
  System.out.println("\n ****TESTING BONUS FEATURE****\n");

  Clock c6 = new Clock(2,30,'p');
  System.out.println ("Non-military clock time: " + c6);
  c6.setMilitary (true);
  System.out.println ("Same clock in military: " + c6);
 }
*/

}










//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//Program:  Clock
//Author: Taylor P.
//Date:  November 30, 2016
//Purpose: Creates a clock class
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Clock
{
 private int hours;
 private int minutes;
 private int seconds;
 private final int hours_Min = 0;
 private final int hours_Max = 23;
 private final int minutes_Min = 0;
 private final int minutes_Max = 59;
 private final int seconds_Min = 0;
 private final int seconds_Max = 59;


//Constructor sets default time to midnight (00:00:00)
 public Clock ()
 {
  this.hours = 00;
  this.minutes = 00;
  this.seconds = 00;
 }

//Constructor sets hours to input value
 public Clock (int h)
 {
  this.hours = h;
  this.minutes = 00;
  this.seconds = 00;
 }

//Constructor sets hours and minutes to input value
 public Clock (int h, int m)
 {
  this.hours = h;
  this.minutes = m;
  this.seconds = 00;
 }

//Constructor sets hours, minutes, seconds to input value
 public Clock (int h, int m, int s)
 {
  this.hours = h;
  this.minutes = m;
  this.seconds = s;
 }

//-------------------------------
//Method: getHours
//Return: int - hours
//Parameters: none
//Purpose: returns hours
//-------------------------------
 public int getHours()
 {
  return this.hours;
 }

//------------------------------
//Method: getMinutes
//Return: int
//Parameters: none
//Purpose: returns minutes
//------------------------------
 public int getMinutes()
 {
  return this.minutes;
 }

//------------------------------
//Method: getSeconds
//Return: int
//Parameters: none
//Purpose: returns seconds
//------------------------------
 public int getSeconds()
 {
  return this.seconds;
 }


//------------------------------
//Method: isPM
//Return: boolean
//Parameter: none
//Purpose: Determines if the time is past noon
//------------------------------
 public boolean isPM ()
 {
  if (this.hours < 12)
   return false;
  else
   return true;
 }

//------------------------------
//Method: setTime
//Return: void
//Parameter: 3 int types - hours, minutes, seconds
//Purpose: set time to (00:00:00) format
//-----------------------------
 public void setTime (int h, int m, int s)
 {
  this.hours = h;
  this.minutes = m;
  this.seconds = s;

 }

//-----------------------------
//Method: addHours
//Return: void
//Parameter: an int type of hours
//Purpose: to add hours together
//-----------------------------
 public void addHours (int h)
 {
  this.hours = this.hours + h;
 }

//-----------------------------
//Method: addMinutes
//Return: void
//Parameter: a int type of minutes
//Purpose: to add minutes together
//-----------------------------
 public void addMinutes (int m)
 {
  this.minutes = this.minutes + m;
 }

//----------------------------
//Method: addMinutes
//Return: void
//Parameter: an int type of seconds
//Purpose: to add seconds together
//----------------------------
 public void addSeconds (int s)
 {
  this.seconds = this.seconds + s;
 }

//-----------------------------
//Method: addTime
//Return: void
//Parameter: three int types of hours, minutes, seconds
//Purpose:
//-----------------------------
 public void addTime (int h, int m, int s)
 {
  this.hours = this.hours + h;
  this.minutes = this.minutes + m;
  this.seconds = this.seconds + s;
 }

//-----------------------------
//Method: equals
//Return:
//Parameter:
//Purpose:
//----------------------------
 public boolean equals (Clock c)
 {
  boolean equiv = c.equals(c);
  return equiv;
 }

//------------------------------
//Method: toString
//Returns:
//Parameters:
//Purpose:
//-----------------------------
 public String toString()
 {
  String string = "";
           if (this.equals(this.hours) && this.equals(this.minutes) && this.equals (this.seconds))
           {
               string = "00:00:00";
           }
           else if (this.equals(this.hours))
           {
      string = "00";
               string = string + ":" + this.minutes + ":" + this.seconds;
           }
           else if (this.equals(this.minutes))
           {
      string = "00";
      string = this.hours + ":" + string + ":" + this.seconds;
     }
     else if (this.equals(this.seconds))
     {
      string = "00";
            string = string + ":" + string + ":" + this.seconds;
     }
     else
      string = string + ":" + this.hours + ":" + this.minutes + ":" + this.seconds;
        return string;

 }

}
```

Comment: You have linked the `Instructions from your teacher` to a local file on your computer. *:D*.. file///Z:/Desktop/CSCI%201301%20Fall%2016/CSCI1301Project7.pdf

Comment: Your `toString` method makes no sense. `this` will never equal `this.seconds` (or any other instance field).

Comment: I will try these answers and let you know if it fixes the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: Now I have to make sure that when times are added they stay within the 23 hours, 60 minutes and 60 seconds.  For instance, at the moment when I add times I get answers like 08:45:135. I need it to be in the proper time format. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recursive call in the `Clock`'s `equals` method. This is the reason you are getting a stack overflow error.

```
public boolean equals (Clock c)
{
    boolean equiv = c.equals(c); // this keeps calling itself
    return equiv;
}
```

Change it to a more appropriate logic to check equality of the `Clock` objects.

For example,

```
public boolean equals (Clock c)
{
    boolean equiv = c!=null && this.hours==c.hours && this.minutes==c.minutes && this.seconds==c.seconds;
    return equiv;
}
```

And also, the `toString()` method is very messy. That would need to be rewritten as well. Something like this:

```
public String toString()
{
    String string = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", this.hours, this.minutes, this.seconds);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I fixed both of those methods and it worked. :)

Comment: Now I have to make sure that the time when added is correct hours, minutes, and seconds. When I complie and it adds times I get answers like 08:45:135.  How do I get the times to have limits? (hours only 0-23, minutes and seconds only 0-59).

Comment: You will need to roll over excess seconds and minutes over to the next unit. For example, if you are left with 135 seconds you'll need to convert that into minutes and add the minutes to your time. So 135 becomes 2 minutes and 15 seconds. This can be obtained by dividing and finding modulus. 135/60 = 2 and 135%60 = 15. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is broken for the `toString` method in `Clock`

```
 if (this.equals (this.hours ....
```

just does not make sense.

Secondly an int with the value `00` is the same as it being `0`

so what you code does is return

```
String.format ("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` method is recursive, and compares `c` to itself; instead, compare the fields of `c` with `this`. Also, you should use the `@Override` annotation. It would have told you that [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) takes an `Object`. Something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Clock) { // <-- Is it a Clock?
        Clock c = Clock.class.cast(o); // <-- Use o as a Clock
        return c.isPM() == this.isPM() //
                && c.getHours() == this.getHours() //
                && c.getMinutes() == this.getMinutes() //
                && c.getSeconds() == this.getSeconds();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your `toString` method could be greatly simplified by creating a simple helper method to pad `int`(s) for two digits. Like,

```
private static String get2Digits(int i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        return "0" + i;
    }
    return String.valueOf(i);
}
```

And then use that to correct `toString` (and use the `@Override` even though you *know* `toString` takes no arguments). You could use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to perform your concatenation.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder(8) //
            .append(get2Digits(hours)) //
            .append(':').append(get2Digits(minutes)) //
            .append(':').append(get2Digits(seconds)) //
            .toString();
}
```